# validation of views before navigating to other in single page application

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation, navigation

I'm new to angular js. I have a form built using bootstrap and also a button is included. button tag is having an

```
<button><a href="#myUrl">Ok</a></button>
```

In single page applicaiton using angular js we use ngRoute to move to other view.
So on click of the button it directs me to next view. Can I validate form before redirecting ?
href will automatic move to other view using ngRoute.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigate the angular form controller which has lots of properties associated with it for form checks

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Also this is a good introduction in how to do bootstrap validation in angular:
http://blog.yodersolutions.com/bootstrap-form-validation-done-right-in-angularjs/

in the context of the above tutorial you could do something like this to your link button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Save</button>
```